# where is the bug of this C code

Tags: c

I was told this is a buggy code, but I don't know why, some could explain it to me.
why there would not be an array out of bound exception when I compile?

```
int a[10];
int j;

void main () {
    int i, j = 42;
    for (i = 0; i <=10; i++) a[i] = i;
    printf("%d", j);
}
```

Comment: You should explain what bug you see?  What did you expect to happen, and what did you actually observe?

Comment: The fact that you have `j` defined right after `a`, and after you overrun the array, you print `j` suggest to me that you perfectly well know what's happening.  Or you need to phrase your question explicitly.  In any case, whatever behavior you see from your program, it is not guaranteed to behave the same everywhere.

Comment: "the" presumes there's only one bug in the code -- which is wrong.

Comment: Another pitfall is that you're doing what's called `variable shadowing`.  The global variable `j` is **not** the same as the variable `j` declared in main().  I suggest you remove the global.

Comment: hey guys, could we justify downvotes? so the user knows. I'm guessing it's because he's not defined the bug, which makes the answers useful, but the question meaningless...

Comment: @Alok Not necessarily "perfectly well know what's happening". Could possibly be "perfectly clueless". Maybe be a homework assignment for someone with zero experience who posted it here rather than examining it himself? I would not fault someone for not seeing the problem(s), though I might fault them for not looking hard before asking. But it's not really fair to assume that either, even though the question is ambiguous, assumptive, and unhelpful.

Comment: if you guys know that I started to learn C two days ago...

Comment: `why there would not be an array out of bound exception when I compile?` C doesn't do bounds checking, either at compile time or at run time. C also does not have "exceptions" although I don't think that's what you meant.

Comment: My programming language teacher told me this was a piece of code found in 1993 by his friend. My teacher want to show me that you have to be aware of Vars, they are dangerous.

Comment: @Alok: I can pretty much guarantee that the program always prints 42.  The j that gets printed is not the same j that gets overwritten by the buffer overflow.

Comment: There is no bug.  It complies with the requirements document you provided.   ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one bug:

```
void main () {
```

should be

```
int main (int argc, char** argv) {
```

Another bug is in your loop.  You write past the end of array `a`, and if your compiler placed `j` in memory immediately following `a` (which based on your question I assume it did), then the out-of-bounds array access will actually end up assigning a value to `j`.  Hence, when you write `10` into `a[10]` (which doesn't exist), you are writing it into the memory where `j` lives (causing this to act like `j = 10`).  However, this behavior is dependent on how your compiler lays out the variables in memory, so you may very well see different behavior if you compiled the same program on a different platform.

Comment: I would say in this case `int main(void)` would be more ideal to convey that this program takes no arguments but it should still return an `int`.

Comment: Not necessarily a bug - it could be that he wants main to return nothing and use no arguments.

Comment: @Michael Dorgan: +1 the C99 standard explicitly allows main to have any return type you (or, more accurately, the implementation) like.

Comment: @Michael Dorgan It doesn't matter what he wants, it matters what the standard mandates. (P.S. an empty parameter list doesn't mean "no arguments") @JeremyP Read more closely; that's only true for freestanding environments.

Answer (score 27):

You've allocated 10 spaces. You fill 11.

Answer (score 6):

Change

```
int a[10];
```

to

```
int a[11];
```

or

```
for (i = 0; i <=10; i++) a[i] = i;
```

to

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) a[i] = i;
```

You've created an array with a count of 10 and try to put 11 elements in it. You either need to put only 10 elements in it or create a bigger array.

Comment: Technically correct, but does not explain *why* it fails in the first place.

Comment: You can also autodetect the size of `a`:

`for (i = 0; i < sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]); i++) a[i] = i;`

Answer (score 1):

filling array crossing the boundary...a[10] is wrong.

Answer (score -2):

There should not be an overflow of array, thats correct as you have mentioned in your question. But some compilers will give a PASS with the code whereas others will trigger a warning (or error is elevated).